# How to create a 'Fake Loading Screen' in Delphi

Tags: delphi, timer, shapes

I've been stretching my brain trying to create a loading screen in Delphi but I just can't find help anywhere.

I am creating a game for a school project and I would like to implement a form that mimics a loading screen.

I want to move a shape across the screen and I want it to leave behind a trail (imitate a progress bar). I know you use timer to smooth it's progression but I'm not sure about how to use a timer correctly with a shape.

I would appreciate it if anyone would show me what code/functions I have to use to do this.

Sincerely,
Kuzon.

Comment: Why "mimic" a loading screen? Why not make an actual loading screen? What's the difference?

Comment: Difference is that the program is a school project as I stated before and an actual loading screen is a bit out of my depth. The 'fake' loading screen is just for aesthetics to make the program appear more 'professional'.

Comment: Who ever downvoted... Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move a shape with a timer and leave a trail:

Each time the timer event fires, adjust the shape position.
The trail is also made with a shape here, by adding the width each timer tick.

```
unit MoveShape;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TFormMoveShape = class(TForm)
    Shape1: TShape;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    Shape2: TShape;
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  FormMoveShape: TFormMoveShape;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

const
  cMoveIncrement = 2;

procedure TFormMoveShape.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (Shape1.Left + Shape1.Width  < Self.ClientWidth - cMoveIncrement) then
  begin
    Shape1.Left := Shape1.Left + cMoveIncrement;
    Shape2.Width := Shape2.Width + cMoveIncrement;
  end
  else
  begin
    Shape1.Left := 8;
    Shape2.Width := 8;
  end;
end;

end.
```

---

```
object FormMoveShape: TFormMoveShape
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form27'
  ClientHeight = 336
  ClientWidth = 635
  Color = clBtnFace
  DoubleBuffered = True
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Shape2: TShape
    Left = 8
    Top = 112
    Width = 8
    Height = 41
    Brush.Color = clAqua
    Shape = stRoundRect
  end
  object Shape1: TShape
    Left = 8
    Top = 112
    Width = 137
    Height = 41
    Shape = stRoundRect
  end
  object Timer1: TTimer
    Interval = 50
    OnTimer = Timer1Timer
    Left = 512
    Top = 24
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This code is extremely helpful and indepth. Loading screen is going to look fantastic. Very much appreciated!